# Parameters numeration in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have bash script with one param that runs fine:

```
if [ "$1" == "output" ]
        then
        echo "strting with output"
        else
        echo "without output"
fi
```

But now I need to use another param that should be independent from first one. That means sometimes firs param might exist and might not.

```
if [ "$2" == "kill" ] 
 then killall myproc 
fi
if [ "$1" == "output" ]
        then
        echo "strting with output"
        else
        echo "without output"
fi
```

This script should work if both params exist. But how to solve problem when I don't need to pass first param?

Comment: "sometimes firs param might exist and might not" .. what? Unless you do something silly like `command "" second-param`, the second parameter **cannot** exist without the first. Perhaps you should look into option strings and `getopts`:  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: muru is right, I didn't understand correctly and posted a silly answer before. As muru said already, if both parameters are optional you should look into `getopts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I believe that it is better to use options in this case (i.e. -o and -k), you can parse the parameters at the start of your script and set variables for each one. i.e.:

```
#!/bin/sh

for x in $@
do
  case $x in
    output)
      OUTPUT=True
      ;;
    kill)
      KILL=True
      ;;
  esac
done


if [ $OUTPUT ]
then
  echo output is set
fi

if [ $KILL ]
then
  echo kill is set
fi
```